# addEventHandler mocking in Jest & Typescript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

This is a plain TS project. No frameworks.

I have [followed through this article here](https://medium.com/@DavideRama/testing-global-event-listener-within-a-react-component-b9d661e59953) whereby the author mocks the `addEventListener` method (on the window however).

I am confused why the mocked function doesn't register as to being called.

```
 console.log
    called in here

      at Object.handleClick [as click] (src/painter/painter.ts:24:13)

 FAIL  src/painter/painter.test.ts
  Painter Setup
    ✕ Should add event handlers to canvas (14 ms)

  ● Painter Setup › Should add event handlers to canvas

    expect(received).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function
```

Simplified implementation:

```
class Painter {
  constructor(target: HTMLCanvasElement) {
    this.canvas = target;
    //...
    this.init();
  }
  init() {
    this.canvas.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick);
  }
  // I know that the this context is wrong here, but trying to simplify the issue
  handleClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log('called in here');
  };
}


// testing
const eventListeners: Record<string, Function> = {};

let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

canvas.addEventListener = jest.fn((eventName: string, callBack: Function) => {
  eventListeners[eventName] = callBack;
}) as jest.Mock;


describe("Painter Setup", function () {
  it("Should add event handlers to canvas", () => {
    const painter = new Painter(canvas);
    eventListeners.click({
      clientX: 0,
      clientY: 0,
    });
    expect(painter.handleClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the missing step was just to use a spy on the handleClick method, to register that the function was indeed called. The handleClick is still called through, rather than mocking it.

```
// testing
const eventListeners: Record<string, Function> = {};

let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

canvas.addEventListener = jest.fn((eventName: string, callBack: Function) => {
  eventListeners[eventName] = callBack;
}) as jest.Mock;

describe("Painter Setup", function () {
  it("Should add event handlers to canvas", () => {
    const spied = jest.spyOn(Painter.prototype, 'handleClick');
    
    const painter = new Painter(canvas);
    
    // this will still call though the original method. Therefore I will see  "called in here" from painter.handleClick
    eventListeners.click({
      clientX: 0,
      clientY: 0,
    });
   
    expect(spied).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the argument received by `toHaveBeenCalled()` (i.e., `painter.handleClick`) was expected to be a mock/spy, but it was not.

You could set `handleClick` to a mock function in your test:

```js
it('...', () => {
  Painter.prototype.handleClick = jest.fn(); // mock handleClick
  const painter = new Painter(canvas);

  //...
  expect(painter.handleClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Comment: Although this does work, this will not call through the original method. I should be expecting to see `'called in here'` in the console. However, you have given me an idea.